# How can I translate the following animation/transitioning to css3?

Tags: html, css

I have a notification system at my gaming website. I did this in After Effects http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcnVYMnTI0A and I would love to set up that animation to my current notification system. This will be used for :

X User is now online
X Started Playing a game

Only problem is that I don't know where to start when it comes to css animations and keyframes. My question, is this possible to do with css keyframes? and if so, Can anyone help or point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far? As far as tutorial is concerned, simply Google "CSS keyframes" or "CSS animation" to find plenty of guides.

Comment: I decided to give this a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/3AuuU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not all that complicated. We first need to start with our markup. I've chosen the following to serve as my structure, but you have all liberty to experiment a bit with with your markup:

```html
<div class="newplayer">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://i.imgur.com/NKc1KMp.png" />
    <img class="videog" src="http://i.imgur.com/GbNxMVX.png" />
    <p>Janice is now online</p>
</div>
```

This doesn't give us much; just a couple images and some text. So we need to style it now. At this point, we're still not getting into anything complicated - just plain old CSS, which you're likely familiar with:

```css
.newplayer, .newplayer p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.newplayer {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: .5em auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 100px;
    border-radius: .25em;
    box-shadow: 0 .15em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.newplayer .avatar, .newplayer .videog {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.newplayer .videog {
    left: 50px;
}
.newplayer p {
    margin: 0;
    left: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold .6em/50px tahoma;
}
```

There's not much here, and it should be fairly straight forward. At this point, we now have the following:

[image: Expanded state]

The next step is to setup the collapsed state. I'm going to indicate that I wish the element to be collapsed by adding a new class to the main container:

```html
<div class="newplayer collapsed">
    ...
</div>
```

Now we need to overwrite our default styles to put this into the closed state:

```css
.collapsed.newplayer {
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
.collapsed.newplayer .videog {
    left: 0;
}
.collapsed.newplayer p {
    width: 0;
}
```

[image: Collapsed state]

Last, but arguably most important, we need to setup which properties on which elements we'd like to transition:

```css
.newplayer, .newplayer p, .newplayer .videog {
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}
```

Now, any time you add this class to the element, it will transition into the collapsed state. In my demo I toggle this class with just a bit of JavaScript:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var label = document.querySelector(".newplayer");

    label.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);

    function toggle() {
        this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
    }

}());
```

Voila, you can see the demo online here: http://jsfiddle.net/3AuuU/

Comment: Wow this amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this with such great detail. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It lookslike it should be relatively easy to animate.  You may not even need keyframes it might just require transitions:

The mozilla site has a pretty good walkthrough:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: Thanks very much for the very useful link, I shall read and attempt to apply it. Also thanks to the others for that awesome -3, you guys rock! :)